# JLabel isn't getting added to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, layout-manager

What am I doing wrong? `layers` is a JPanel. I am trying to add the JLabel below to the `JPanel`, but nothing happens. I tried added `repaint()` to the panel but that doesn't do anything either. What am I not doing?

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
lbl.setText("Layer " + numLayers);
lbl.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 12));
lbl.setVerticalTextPosition(1);
lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
lbl.setVisible(true);
layers.add(lbl);
```

Comment: Is this occurring during runtime? If so, are you calling `revalidate()` then `repaint()` on the JPanel after adding the label? Also, what layout manager does the JPanel use?

Comment: `revalidate()` fixed the problem.

Comment: Well, there you go! The reason why this works: revalidate tells the layout managers to accept the new components (or the removed components) and re-layout all components.

Comment: Okay cool! I didn't know that. Each label is added from time to time, how can I add in a list format from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to `revalidate()` the panel

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> ...Each label is added from time to time, how can I add in a list format from top to bottom?

Here is where you probably would use a JList rather than multiple JLabels. You have quite a bit of flexibility on how the information on the list is displayed and it is easy to add new items to the list's model.

Comment: But... I don't want it to act or look like a list, I just want it to display like a list. I am building a "Layers" menu, just like "Gimp" or "PhotoShop".

Comment: *" I am building a "Layers" menu, just like "Gimp".."*  Emulating that GUI is a very bad sign.  :(

Comment: @RyanNaddy: please let me know more about what it is exactly you're trying to do.